# How to solve the issue of "%" on Calculator giving different results on iPhone vs Mac?

Tags: macos, bug

To see the result of

```
2000 × 19% / 12
```

I used both the Mac's Calculator app (with El Capitan or Mavericks), vs on the iPhone with iOS 9.1.

On the Mac, when I press `2000`, `×`, `19`, `%`, it gives me `380`, but when I press the division button `÷`, then it gives `760000` right away, and finishing with pressing `12`, `=` gives `63333.33333333`.

On the iPhone, I do get the expected result:  `31.6666`.  So how can this be understood and how can it be done on the Mac?

Answer (score 4):

Here's a short article that does a good job of describing the behaviour you're observing with OS X's in-built Calculator app: [How does the calculator percent key work?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080110-00/?p=23853)

### What's going on?

When performing an operation involving two values followed by the percent key, the product is first calculated (i.e. `2000 x 19 %` = `380`) and this then replaces the second value in the *ongoing* calculation, which becomes `2000 x 380`. When you then press the division key `÷` the product of the ongoing operation is calculated (`2000 x 380 = 760,000`), as you described, before you input the divisor to perform another operation.

### Working with percentages using OS X's in-built Calculator

To work with percentages in this instance you should express them in decimal form:

```
2000 × 0.19 ÷ 12
= 31.6666
```

This works with both iOS's and OS X's Calculator. I would advise against using the percent key in favour of working with decimals. The same can be said when using physical calculators, where the behaviour can differ between models. Recent upgrades of macOS have fixed this order of operations change if you need to enter % as described.

Comment: thanks for your answer.  I am somewhat stunned to know of "the way to use it on the Mac is not to use it"

Comment: I read this as reminding you how to work around a bug in order of operations and not  to not use it. I've answered on an upgrade / alternative if you can't live with any specific built in calculator. PCalc has never let me down yet @nonopolarity

Answer (score 0):

[I would use PCalc for more accurate calculations](https://www.pcalc.com/mac/index.html) if edge cases that expose the reality of floating point math is [something you consider broken for your needs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/588014/475228) or the order of operations isn't as you expect.

Upgrading to Monterey fixes the issue you mentioned and the result is **31.666666666666667**